# Combining variable to reference another variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following problem, I have a list of variables `A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3`.
I want to cycle through these using two `For Each` Loops.

I have something like the below:

```
For Each Alphabet In Array("A", "B", "C")
   For Each Number In Array ("1", "2", "3")
   
   Next Number
Next Alphabet
```

My question is, how would I be able to string together alphabet and number so it references the variables?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary with keys such as "A1", etc.? Whenever you find yourself with a number of similarly named variables that you are trying to iterate over, you are probably using the wrong data structure.

Comment: If they're declared as public fields in a class, you'll be able to use `CallByName`

Comment: @JohnColeman I never knew such a thing existed.  I will take a look at that now.  Just a quick google looks like it might be able to solve my problem!

Comment: This question looks like a [X/Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You asked X but your actual problem is Y. So I think you should more explain **why** you think you need that and explain your actual problem (what are you trying to achieve with that). Looks like you are already up the wrong tree.